# REACT ref.current is null in conditional rendered component

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering, react-forwardref

i'd like to achieve open react-datepicker calendar on button click outside of this component with ref. It is working fine if its outside of conditional rendering. If i put into a condition statementm i'll get TypeError: this.calendarRef.current is null. It is class component and calendarRef is defined in constructor.

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const MyCustomDatePicker = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
   <DatePicker
    ref={ref}
    selected={new Date()}
    popperPlacement="bottom-start"
    monthsShown={2}
   />
));

class DateRangeCustom extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          currentDate: '01/12/2021',
          ddCalendarOn: false,
          endDate: '08/12/2021',
    };

    this.calendarRef = React.createRef();
}

handleCalendarBtnClick = () => {
    console.log('*** HANDLE CALENDAR BTN ***');
    this.setState((state) => ({
        ddCalendarOn: !state.ddCalendarOn
    }));
    this.calendarRef.current.setOpen(true);
}

render() {
    console.log('*** render ****')
    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid>
                <Grid container direction="column">
                    <Button
                        onClick={this.handleCalendarBtnClick}
                    >
                        SHOW
                    </Button>
                    {this.state.ddCalendarOn && <MyCustomDatePicker
                        ref={this.calendarRef}
                    />}                        
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default DateRangeCustom;
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Why do you declare `MyCustomDatePicker` inside another component? Where is ay conditional rendering occurring that you are referring to? Can you include a full component example so we may see everything that touches that `calendarRef`?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you, my fault with copying and cleaning my code, for easyiest example. Is there better way how to get ref to child component? i found it in some example that's the reason :) i'm new in react and still learning. Thank you for any help:)

Comment: @DrewReese you were right, no need for ref or some inner component declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,

pretty easy thing and stupid mistake. There's no need for using ref or forwardRef. Just set open to the same variable as is in condition for rendering makes it work.

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

class DateRangeCustom extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          currentDate: '01/12/2021',
          ddCalendarOn: false,
          endDate: '08/12/2021',
    };
}

handleCalendarBtnClick = () => {
    console.log('*** HANDLE CALENDAR BTN ***');
    this.setState((state) => ({
        ddCalendarOn: !state.ddCalendarOn
    }))
}

render() {
    console.log('*** render ****')
    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid>
                <Grid container direction="column">
                    <Button
                        onClick={this.handleCalendarBtnClick}
                    >
                        SHOW
                    </Button>
                    {this.state.ddCalendarOn && <DatePicker
                       open={this.state.ddCalendarOn}
                       selected={new Date()}
                       popperPlacement="bottom-start"
                       monthsShown={2}
                    />}                        
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default DateRangeCustom;
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was refering to. But you can omit " {this.state.ddCalendarOn && " as well. I would think that the calendar is only rendered when open so there is no loss in removing this conditional rendering.

Comment: @ChrissiGrilus no, if i omit that statement, input textfield of datepicker will be rendered by default. set flag to open cause that datepicker will be rendered with input and also calendar.

Comment: That is weird but as long as it works for you thats great. Which UI lib are you using?

Comment: @ChrissiGrilus Most of the time Material UI

Answer (score 0):

The ref is registered on the component once rendered. But you render it conditionally with: this.state.ddCalendarOn
and then try to call it imperativly directly. This will not work because a state change will cause a render and only then the ref is registered.

I would try to use a more declarative approach, I would think that the API allows that. Something like:

```
<MyCustomDatePicker ref={this.calendarRef} open={this.state.ddCalendarOn}/>
```

Then you handle the open state on the Callendar component itself. React has in mind to use this declarative approach whenever possible and only seldomly you will have to use a ref to imperativly call something. The Callendar will not render when you set its "open" prop to false, the result should be the same.

Comment: Thank you, Chrissi, i found out there's no nead for ref or custom picker... beginners mistake... Your answer pushed me to correct direction. Thank you :)